# Bind dynamically created Textbox array to a string array or List<string>

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, data-binding

I need to bind an array of dynamically created textboxes to a string[] or List<string>. This was the closest [WinForm Controls binding to a List<T> problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793997/winform-controls-binding-to-a-listt-problem) but no cigar.

Typically for single textboxes I bind the Textboxes' Text property:

```
Engine engine = new Engine();
public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    txtQuery.DataBindings.Add("Text",engine,"Query");
}
```

To a class property:

```
public class Engine : IEngine, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 private string query;
 public string Query
 {
    get { return query; }
    set
    {
        query = value;
        InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Query"));
    }
 }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
 }
}
```

---

I've given it a go with an array of textboxes and strings without luck:

Front End:

```
TextBox[] txtBoxArr = new TextBox[numberOfDimensions];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDimensions;i++)
{
    string tabName = "Dataset" + (i + 1);
    tabCtrlDatasets.TabPages.Add(tabName,tabName);
    txtBoxArr[i] = new TextBox();
    txtBoxArr[i].Name = "txtDataset" + i ;
    txtBoxArr[i].DataBindings.Add("Text",engine,"Dataset");
    tabCtrlDatasets.TabPages[i].Controls.Add(txtBoxArr[i]);
}
```

Back End:

```
private string[] dataset;
public string[] Dataset
{
    get { return dataset; }
    set
    {
        dataset = value;
        InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Dataset"));
    }
}
```

**To get it working I need to know the index of the item in the array. I cant recall doing this before, does anyone know how to identify the index of the textbox to bind it to the correct item in the string array?**

*I'm a bit tired today and having a memory block.*

Comment: If someone see's this can they please give me a hint as to why my questions end up destined for a "[Tumbleweed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-tumbleweed-badge)" badge?

Comment: I am working on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a string array for holding the `TextBox` values, you could use a `DataTable` with a single row. In this way, you don't have to increase the complexity of your `Engine` class (as it will still have a single property) and you can bind the textboxes to the `engine.DataTable`'s `DataColumnCollection` (mapping them by the column's index).

Try this in the form:

```
Engine engine = new Engine();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("column0");
    dt.Columns.Add("column1");
    dt.Columns.Add("column2");
    dt.Rows.Add("abc", DateTime.Now, 123456, 789.0123F);
    engine.DataTable = dt;

    int numberOfDimensions = engine.DataTable.Columns.Count;
    TextBox[] txtBoxArr = new TextBox[numberOfDimensions];
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDimensions; i++)
    {
        string tabName = "Dataset" + (i + 1);
        tabCtrlDatasets.TabPages.Add(tabName, tabName);
        txtBoxArr[i] = new TextBox();
        txtBoxArr[i].Name = engine.DataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        txtBoxArr[i].DataBindings.Add("Text", 
            engine.DataTable, txtBoxArr[i].Name);
        tabCtrlDatasets.TabPages[i].Controls.Add(txtBoxArr[i]);
    }
}
```

and modify the `Engine` class like this:

```
private DataTable dataTable;
public DataTable DataTable
{
    get
    {
        return dataTable;
    }
    set
    {
        dataTable = value;
        InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DataTable"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm open to this approach, I'll give it go tomorrow. +1 Thanks. If you're awake could you please elaborate on your findings with binding a control[], what made you resort to a `DataTable`?

Comment: Thanks for your help on this Alex, am still keen to hear alternatives but marking your answer as correct in the mean time.